# powershell: if result is empty after a command, out some text

Tags: powershell

I am making a script to get accounts in Outlook. To do it, I retrieve .pst and .ost files. But if there isn't any file, I want to write an output like "no files was found"
This is my code:

```
 get-childitem -path C:\users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook*  -recurse -force -dept 1 -include *.ost, *.pst | select-object fullname, @{name='Size_MB';expression={$_.length /1MB -as [int]}}, lastwritetime | Sort-Object -Property Size_MB -Descending | out-file c:\test.txt
```

I have tried a lot of things but nothing works... any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard approach would be to assign the results of your Get-ChildItem to a variable and have an if/else handle it from there.

Something like:

```
$OutlookAccounts = $null;
$OutlookAccounts = get-childitem -path C:\users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook*  -recurse -force -dept 1 -include *.ost, *.pst | select-object fullname, @{name='Size_MB';expression={$_.length /1MB -as [int]}}, lastwritetime;

If ($OutlookAccounts -ne $null)
{
$OutlookAccounts | Sort-Object -Property Size_MB -Descending | out-file c:\test.txt;
}
Else
{
Write-Host "No files found";
}
```

Comment: That do the job!  Very nice!

Thanks a lot!!!!!!  you make me happy ;)